# Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime from 4.3.1 to 4.3.0

Tags: .net-core, nuget, teamcity, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-restore

```
.NET Core 2.2.0
TeamCity Professional 2019.1.2 (build 66342)

build step .NET CLI dotnet restore

error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime from 4.3.1 to 4.3.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.

error NU1605:  MyTestProject -> MyProject -> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.6 -> Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.1 -> System.Runtime.Extensions 4.3.1 -> System.Runtime (>= 4.3.1)

error NU1605:  MyTestProject -> MyProject -> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.6 -> Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.1 -> System.Runtime (>= 4.3.0)
```

Local Visual Studio build runs clean with no such restore errors.

But TeamCity build throws many errors this type.

I have two questions :

1. How to reliably resolve this error ?

Please note that adding package references to .csproj is not a good option because my build has a lot of errors of this type.  Potentially it would be required to add an explicit `PackageReference` to every leaf package in the dependencies tree.

2. Why does `MSBUILD` consider this to be an error and not a warning ?

To my eye the version constraints are compatible because `4.3.1` satisfies both constraints `System.Runtime (>= 4.3.1)` and `System.Runtime (>= 4.3.0)`.

Isn't that what the author of `Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.1` intended ?

A similar type of error is happening in four distinct builds ( in four distinct apps ) :

```
[restore] MyApp.csproj: error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational from 2.2.1 to 2.2.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
MyApp.csproj: error NU1605:  MyApp -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.2.1 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 2.2.1)
MyApp.csproj: error NU1605:  MyApp -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 2.2.0 && < 2.3.0)
MyApp.csproj: error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore from 2.2.1 to 2.2.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
MyApp.csproj: error NU1605:  MyApp -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory 2.2.1 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.2.1)
MyApp.csproj: error NU1605:  MyApp -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.2.0 && < 2.3.0)
```

Because I began seeing these errors in all four builds around the same time, and because there are no code commits which plausibly could have caused the errors ( and definitely not across all four apps ), it leads me to believe that something was changed on the Build Agent ( which is shared with others ).

Or what could cause many app restores to simultaneously begin failing with these errors ?

Comment: Check for duplicate PackageReference entries in your csproj file. I think I ran into the same issue